# How to change linux machine IP from command line?

Tags: linux, ip

Using "ifconfig", the IP address resets to old IP address after a reboot. How to make the change permanent?

Comment: you need to edit file for that `/etc/network/interfaces`, with `ifconfig` its not possible.

Answer (score 4):

In the file `/etc/network/interfaces` (for a Debian based distro) you can set your desired static ip address.

For example for network interface `eth0`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

For a CentOS/Fedora like distro, you should edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, which looks like:

```
DEVICE=eth0
 TYPE=Ethernet
 ONBOOT=yes
 BOOTPROTO=none
 IPADDR=192.168.1.2
 PREFIX=24
 GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
 IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
 NAME="System eth0"
```